# Pandas: slice by named index using loc, but not include first index

Tags: pandas, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe with named indexes, need to select all above particular index, not including it.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
```

|  | max_speed | shield |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cobra | 1 | 2 |
| viper | 4 | 5 |
| sidewinder | 7 | 8 |

I need to select df below `cobra`. So like pseudo code: `df.loc['cobra'+1 : ]`

Comment: you can use .iloc[1:] to do it based on the position of cobra

Comment: `df.iloc[df.index.get_indexer(['cobra'])[0]+1:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to go about this:

```
>>> df.iloc[df.index.tolist().index('cobra')+1:]
            max_speed  shield
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8

>>> df.drop('cobra', axis=0)
            max_speed  shield
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8

>>> df[df.index != 'cobra']
            max_speed  shield
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8
```

An addition method that [@Quang Hoang proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70277896/pandas-slice-by-named-index-using-loc-but-not-include-first-index/70278000#comment124232181_70277896):

```
>>> df.iloc[df.index.get_indexer(['cobra'])[0]+1:]
            max_speed  shield
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting without include cobra:

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_indexer(['cobra'])[0]+2:,:]
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]],
     index=['cobra', 'viper', 'sidewinder'],
     columns=['max_speed', 'shield'])
print(df.loc[df.index > 'cobra'])
```

output

```
            max_speed  shield
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8
```